# Custom text when referencing a python class in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

Generating my documentation with Sphinx, I can do the following without problems:

```
See the definition in :py:class:`MyClass`
```

and it works as expected.

But now I would like to use the standard way to use a custom text for the link:

```
See the definition in `Custom Text <:py:class:`MyClass`>`
```

and it does not work.

I cannot use

```
See the definition in `Custom Text<MyClass>`
```

because the link points to a different section also named `MyClass`, and which I rather not change.

What is the right way to explicitly indicate that I am referring to the class and not the section?

I figure I can put an anchor `.. _myclass:` just before the definition of MyClass (which I manually wrote in another file, it is not apidoc generated) but I wonder if what I am asking is possible.

EDIT:

I have noticed I can do:

```
See the definition in :py:class:`Custom text<MyClass>`
```

and it generates the right link with the custom text. The only thing is that the rendered text has the format of a `:py:` reference (kind of ugly) and not the standard cross-reference formatting (same font type underlined and blue).

Comment: Try :ref:`My Label <py:class:MyClass>`. Alternatively you can customize the theme's default styles as you like.

Comment: Meh, SO renders backticks as literals, so insert a backtick after `:ref:` and after `>`.